# Jenkins Pipeline: how to use the libraries built during previous stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have decided to setup some Continous Integration process on our multi-repositories project. The idea is to automatically build for all target environments, and run the regression tests.
Jenkins seems like a comprehensive FOSS solution for that purpose, and it promotes the use of its Pipeline plugin.

For the examle, let's assume we have library **A**, which is a required dependency of library **B**. We created a freestyle project *build A*, which successfully clones and compiles **A**.
From [the documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) and the snippet generator, we started a pipeline whose first step is to run *build A*:

```
node {
   stage 'Build dependencies'
   build 'build A'
   //
   stage 'Build executable'
   git url: 'git@gitrepo:projectB', credentialsId: 'jenkins'
   sh 'cmake -DPATH_TO_A=XXX ./'
   // We do not know what to do then to use the built dependencies ?
   // In particular, XXX should be replaced by a path to the header and binaries 
   // provided by A's build step.
}
```

We were unable to find how to then use this built dependency **A** in the build of the project **B**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try copy the libA into the libB so that you can access it.

For detail, you can ref this

https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/copying-artifacts-between-builds-jenkins-workflow

Comment: Thank you for this pointer. Could you please add a minimal code example of how that could be done in the context of the question, so your answer would be self-sufficient ?

Comment: You can do something like this node {
   stage 'Build dependencies'
   build 'build A'
   //
   stage 'Build executable'
   git url: 'git@gitrepo:projectB', credentialsId: 'jenkins'
      step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
          projectName: 'build A',
          filter: 'target/builda.zip', target: '.']);

   sh 'cmake -DPATH_TO_A=./builda.zip'
   // We do not know what to do then to use the built dependencies ?
   // In particular, XXX should be replaced by a path to the header and binaries 
   // provided by A's build step.
}

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the code example, it would be much more redeable :)

Answer (score 0):

## Using folder notation

It should be pretty straightforward to get your other job using simple folder notation : `../project-A-name` from your current pipeline's workspace.

Your script would look like :

```java
node {
   stage 'Build dependencies'
   def jobAName = "A"
   build "build ${jobAName}"

   stage 'Build executable'
   git url: 'git@gitrepo:projectB', credentialsId: 'jenkins'
   sh "cmake -DPATH_TO_A=../${jobAName}/yourartifact"
}
```

Note that I replaced the simple quotes of your `cmake` step with double quotes to enable variable substitution.

Also you will note that I defined a variable to record the name of `job A` but of course you could just use the name of your job directly in the `build` and `sh` steps, but I find repeating constants error-prone.

## Using Copy Artifact Plugin

As Tim mentionned it in his answer, you can also use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy job A artifact to your current `project B` pipeline. Your pipeline would look like this :

```java
node {
   stage 'Build dependencies'
   def jobAName = "A"
   build "build ${jobAName}"

   stage 'Build executable'
   step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: "${jobAName}", filter: 'target/yourartifact', target: '.']); 
   sh 'cmake -DPATH_TO_A=yourartifact'
}
```

Again, I've used a variable and double quotes for variable substitution.

In this step `filter` param will allow you to select the relative path of your artifact within project A workspace while the `target` param will specify where you want to copy the artifact within project B workspace.